# Design algorithm for an expression with multiple sums

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I am trying to write a code to compute the below math formula:

$$A(N,M,f)=\sum_{{n_1}=0}^N\sum_{n_2=0}^{n_1}\cdots\sum_{n_{M-1}}^{n_{M-2}}f(n_1,n_2,...,n_{M-1})$$

When $M$ is small, we can use several "for-loops", i.e., $M=3$,

for $n_1=0:N$

for $n_2=0:n_1$

compute $f(n_1,n_2)$

end

end

However, when $M$ is very large (e.g., $M=1000$), it is not a good idea to write 1000 "for-loops". Does anyone have any suggestion please? Thank you.

Comment: It's not about an algorithm, it's about language syntax. Also, note that if $M = 1000$, and at least $10\%$ of cycles have at least two iterations, you have at least $2^{100}$ terms in your sum, which is impossible to compute in any sane time.

Comment: @mihaild: Thanks for sharing your perspective. My point is that suppose that we don't care about computational complexity (e.g., $M=100$ and powerful processor), how to write a code compute the above expression when the value of $M$ changes, so that we do not have to do manually for each value of $M$.